# Method for exporting drawn flash/flex UIComponent to vector based print file

Tags: apache-flex, flash, pdf, vector, export

I am creating a flex application where I am using the built in graphics package of flex 3 to draw shapes and things to a UIComponent.  I want to be able to export this vector image UIComponent to a vector based file, pdf, eps etc.  Are there any tools, libraries, or methods for doing so?

I looked at AlivePDF - which works very slick, but its output is effectively a snapshot of the UIComponent drawn out as a bitmap to the PDF.  I want true vector output, as this image is for print, needs to be able to scale and be color correct.

I read somewhere that it may be possible with Adobe Live Cycle, but in looking at the documentation I'm not sure how to use it.

Another possibility is to submit the final image parameters to a server-side PHP script that would re-generate the image in SVG format.  But as I understand SVG is not ideal for print, and this is lots of extra work.

Any thoughts, ideas, methods?  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the vector-based file, and what formats are acceptable? Are you just looking for something that can be printed in high-quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others, I ended up using alivePDF.  Worked great.